# Can't cURL Lightsail server from Lightsail servers: SSL certificate problem

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, amazon-lightsail

I have many php projects running on Lightsail LAMP servers. Recently they have stopped working because they are failing to call a Wordpress API running on another server. I can cURL this endpoint from my machine but when I attempt to from any of my Lightsail servers I receive back "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

the certificate for this website does not expire for a month and when I curl from localhost this is confirmed when running the verbose flag on the curl. I have also checked that the whole certificate chain is intact and it seems to be.

Output when hitting server from another server(or from itself):

```
bitnami@<server address>:~$ curl -I https://<server address> -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost/
*   Trying <server address>...
* Connected to <server address> port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /opt/bitnami/common/openssl/certs/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

output when from local machine:

```
*   Trying <server address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <server address> (<server address>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=<server address>
*  start date: Aug  9 22:55:44 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  7 22:55:42 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<server address>" matched cert's "<server address>"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user <auth code>
> HEAD <path> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <server address>
> Authorization: Basic <auth code>
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Any ideas on why this is occurring would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that 'intact' chain LE's 'compatibility' chain that enables the old DST X3 root (on Android) or the 'ISRG-only' chain? Does the failing curl use OpenSSL 1.0.2 (check with `curl -V`) and does the CAfile it uses include the DST root? **OpenSSL 1.0.2 with the DST root in its truststore fails to verify the LE compatibility chain since Sept. 30.** There are at least a dozen Qs on this over the past two weeks; please see some of them or https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ and https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely caused by the LetsEncrypt certificate expiration.
Check:
https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/